# Git interactive rebase of another branch on current branch but NOT onto HEAD

Tags: git, git-rebase

I was wondering if there was a way to do an interactive rebase from one branch onto the current branch but not onto the head. Kind of like combination of `git rebase -i otherbranch` and `git rebase -i HEAD~2`.

What I want to do is be presented with an interactive rebase file where i can arrange not only the commits from the remote branch but also a range of commits on the current branch beginning from the head.

The scenario I have is:

- i have feature branch B1
- while waiting for code review I started a new feature by branching from B1. The new branch is B2
- code review finally happened and I had to fix something in B1
- changes are applied to B1 by way of an amend (not a new commit)

Now I need to update B2 with the revised commit from B1. I want the revised the commit to replace the original commit.

Simply rebasing B1 into B2 will result in the original and the revised commit appearing in B2's history (and there will probably be some nasty merge conflicts).

If I could get the B1 unique commits and a range of B2's commits in the interactive rebase prompt then i can tell git to discard the old version of the commit and use the new one from B1 in it's place all in one operation.

So it might look something like: `git rebase -i B1 HEAD~2`

Currently I do this by branching B1 into `temp` then cherry-picking the new commit from B2 onto it, erase B2 then move temp to B2. Which is fine I guess... but if i could do it as part of a rebase it would be nicer (i think).

Comment: Commit in a child branch that have to be amended is not usually present in other branches. Please review the question to reduce inconsistency.

Comment: What? Do you mean my question didn't make sense?

Comment: Yes, I suspect you mistyped in "Subsequently a problem was found in B1, repaired and applied with git amend" B1 should be  B2, which is a source branch. Child branch fixups rarely cause duplications.

Comment: Just use the full spelling, `git rebase --onto $newbase $oldbase $branch`

Comment: Also title is not consistent with the question body.."not onto HEAD"?

Comment: Uggh yeah I see what you mean. B1 is actually the source branch, B2 is the branch created from B1. Sorry, I had a bit of trouble articulating the scenario, will fix it up.

Comment: @jthill are $newbase and $oldbase commit hashes?

Comment: That or however else you want to refer to a commit

Comment: Yeah... I'm not getting it. With B1 checked out I ran: git rebase -i --onto master B2.

This brought up a interactive file with the commit from B1 listed. The output said it had update B1 head (not what I wanted) but as far as I can see nothing has changed in either branch.

Comment: Ok I ran: git rebase -i --onto B1 master B2
This brought up an interactive prompt showing my new commit in B2 and the old (changed in B1) commit. I discarded the old commit and ended up with a log of B2 that was identical to B1 plus the new commit in B2 at the HEAD. Only problem is I dont understand why this works/what I just did. @jthill do you want to post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 4):

That's a case for `git rebase -i --onto` as @jthill pointed out. To understand what you do fire up gitk - so if you have:

```
A - B - c - D    B2
     \
      C'         B1
```

(where C' is your amended commit) you just issue `git rebase -i --onto C' C B1` where the C, C' are the SHAs of the commits (or temporary branch names you checkout on your commits) and they are ***excluded*** from the rebase. Note the `-i` is not strictly needed although if you run into conflicts it is much better to be in an interactive rebase while solving them (allows you to edit the commit message, while non interactive will just accept the resolution and march on, although *much* faster than the interactive one).

Result:

```
A - B - c - D    reflog
     \
      C'         B1
       \
        D'       B2
```

Same, if you have:

```
A - B - c - D - E    B2
     \
      C' - D'        B1
```

So you amended commit C and so commit D changed too (although its contents are the same) - issue `git rebase -i --onto D' D B1`.

Rebase is the most important git command IMO, gets code writing to the level it should be, you can apply your changes wherever you want in whatever order.

Always post diagrams like the above when asking a question.

Comment: Thanks for your diagrams, I scrolled down looking for someone who had done this in order to understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

Rebasing is indeed `cherry-pick`-ing a few commits in turn. The file edited in `git rebase -i` specifies what commits to pick, and in which order.

We can even replace one commit with another in B1, without a temp branch, like:

```
# this is the file get edited in `rebase -i`
# pick commit-in-B2        # the default when rebasing B2, comment out it
pick commit-in-B1          # instead pick the amended commit in B1
pick rest-of-B2
```

Comment: Ok. If I just do a rebase and add the old hash in as a discard would that do it? Ill try, was hoping for a way to gen the file for me